# "NameError: global name 'ser' is not defined" python twitter

Tags: python, pyserial

I have the following problems in Python, but I have no idea why:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):   File
C:/Users/W7-32/Downloads/TW31.py", line 82, in <module>
    driptwit()  ## Llamada a la funcion driptwit   File "C:/Users/W7-32/Downloads/TW31.py", line 71, in driptwit
    ser.write("1") NameError: global name 'ser' is not defined
```

The source code:

```
 # lIBRERIAS

 import twitter
 import tweepy
 import serial
 import time
 import threading
 import os
 import datetime

 ##Consumer y Access de Twitter Developers from tweepy import API
 consumer_key = 'QpaLpmQOS0DMTt2hFxy5WN40i'
 consumer_secret = 'WoUssPI9gIdiEIu0LSWG2bvGuAlvF8WTDStdFTkj5OIPwbeLth'
 access_token_key = '935906436-aMBTKoPOZshZhCRRil1vNCTUKPxQBSiuXe181hLp'
 access_token_secret = 'pxYs26cMqxQbhxQtgfIGnUjWGP1eLlK9mVxdaLeorPfZ4'

 #Autenticacion y conexion con Twitter
 #auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 ##auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

 #api = tweepy.api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, >     access_token_secret)
 #api=tweepy.API(auth)
 ##Declaracion del puerto serial

 auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

 api=tweepy.API(auth)


 locations = ['COM3','COM4','COM5','COM6']

 for device in locations:

     try:

         ser = serial.Serial(device, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8,

         parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

         print ("\nArduino found on: " + ser.portstr + " please >     wait...\n")
         time.sleep(2)
         break
     except:
                 print "Failed to connect on", device

 ## check serial port
 def checkokay():
     ser.flushInput()
     time.sleep(3)
     line = ser.readline()
     time.sleep(3)
     if line == ' ':
         line = ser.readline()
     print("here")


 print('Bienvenido a Print_Twitter')


 def driptwit():
     status = []
     x = 0
     status = api.user_timeline('FerCMejia')  ##grab latest statuses
     checkit = [s.text for s in status]  ##put status in an array
     drip = checkit[0].split()  ##split first tweet into words

     ## check for match and write to serial if match
     if (drip[0] == '#dripPrint'):
         print("Recibiendo Twitter, Imprimiendo")
         ser.write("1")
     else:
         if drip[0] == '#dripPrintStop':  ##break if done
             ser.write("0")
             print("Impresion detenida, esperando instruccion")
         else:
                 print("Esperando Tweet")
                 ser.write("0")


 while 1:
         driptwit()  ## Llamada a la funcion driptwit
         time.sleep(20)  ## Espera de 20 seg para volver a leer el status
```

Although the port has the Arduino connected, it gives me that error of being undefined.

Here is the .py archive:

[Archive Python](https://mega.nz/#!1ttliJZB!FAzKkMF1KRnS1bdzyBMdXBV5yLzCdLh4xL9OtHrRCVw)

I use Pycharm and the Python2.7 interpreter, Windows7 32 bit.

Comment: Please show your code in your question.  Most likely you are trying to use a name which is either mis-spelt or out of scope.

Comment: Seconded. In addition to the fact that links like Mega are suspicious, you should reduce your code to a [mcve] to isolate the problem rather than asking us to spending our time doing the same, given that the community freely gives its time to help.

Comment: Ready,its correct now ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ser` is not a global variable. You define it inside of your for loop, therefore its scope is limited to that loop. Above the for loop do this:

```
ser = None
for device in locations:
```

This makes its scope not just limited to the for loop. The for loop will now use that variable that was just defined when it calls it in the loop. 
Then, in the body of the functions, you'll want to add the `global` keyword at the top to be sure that when you call `ser` it's getting the global variable not trying to create a new one. Like this:

```
def checkokay():
     global ser
     ser.flushInput()
```

Same in the other function:

```
def driptwit():
     global ser
     status = []
```

Now your variable is global and your functions are using the global version of the variable.